# Vuex: when to use state versus getters?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

When retrieving data from Vuex, in some cases the choice between using getters and access state directly is quite clear.  For example:

- If I'm retrieving a simple scalar, such as the value of the `count` variable, accessing the state directly seems to make sense
- If I'm retrieving a filtered list of item however, a getter is the clear choice.

But what about other cases where there is only a slight amount of logic required to retrieve a value?  For example, what if I have a `foo` object in the root of my store, and:

- I want to retrieve a value such as foo.option, but I'm not sure if it exists.  I would usually use a ternary operator to check for the existence of the value, and either return the value or return null.
- I want to retrieve foo.date, but date is a string so I want it converted to a moment.

Either of these needs could be met using a `mapState` function, but should I be using `mapGetter` instead?  What's the difference?

Comment: In your foo object case, i would continue to use state. depends on where you use, you might need different use cases. for example, date display in template is clearly vue filter. but foo.option might be a logic value, so you can simplify your object with some utility library like lodash.

Answer (score 2):

> Either of these needs could be met using a mapState function

True... but what happens if more than 1 component needs the "slightly altered" value? You'd end up with duplicate logic. In that case perform the "slight amount of logic" in a getter.

Comment: Hi @EricGuam, I put the mapState logic in a separate file anyhow, so there is no duplication.